# How to best partition Airflow jobs that work on data that cannot be partioned by date

Tags: python, airflow, scheduled-tasks, quota

I have some DAGs already defined in Airflow that perform queries on third party APIs, pull some data partitioned by date (for example the trending items for yesterday) and write them to the DB. They can also be triggered manually with a bunch of parameters to download the same items without the date-based logic. So far so good, this is a standard scenario for Airflow.

I now want to reuse and adapt some of these dags to perform special queries: in Airflow's terms this means receiving different Job's parameters. I can do it one by one manually but clearly this is not the best. The main reason is that these third party APIs have daily quota thresholds that we don't want to cross. So we are not free to run everything every day but we need to be considerate with the executions.

So let's say I want to download 100 entities, which ID I can download through a service call and let's say my quota is 10 per day. One solution would be to create a DAG that does the call, saves the ids into a database with the date in which they should be executed, but I'm doing the Airflow scheduler's job and it seems not good.There are many things that could go wrong.

I could do the same trick but with something that looks like a queue: one manual DAG puts tasks in the queue and another, daily, DAG pulls from the queue. This one kinda works in my mind but it seems like a lot of effort and I'm not sure what should keep track of the queue. Something like Celery seems like an overkill so probably I would have to use a database. Still, it seems like over engineering and some kind of Airflow anti-pattern but I don't have much experience with the tool so feedbacks are welcome.

Are there other options? Is there some Airflow's feature that would solve this easily?

Comment: I think this is a pretty typical use-case for XComs but it is essentially the same thing that you're mentioning (writing to a DB with a list of Ids) except it is handled in Airflow itself.

Comment: with the Xcoms how? I know how to use Xcoms to transfer information from a task to the next inside a DAG. Is there more to it?